# Groovy: Parsing List elements

Tags: java, parsing, jenkins, groovy, hash

For learning purpose, I like to parse the following look up table as follows:
I want to check the branch name and fetch the corresponding name value, but i want to do fetch first name of each branch, like : [branch: "test"] => name "a" than [branch: "test-1"] => name "d" ; and so on,

```
LUT = [
    [branch: "test", name: 'a', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test", name: 'b', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test", name: 'c', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-1", name: 'd', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-1", name: 'e', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-2", name: 'f', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-2", name: 'g', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-2", name: 'h', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-3", name: 'i', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-3", name: 'j', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-4", name: 'k', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-5", name: 'l', image_name: 'abc'],
]
```

for example the result may look like:

```
result = {
 "test": [{ "name":"a" }],
 "test-1": [{ "name":"d" }],
 "test-2": [{ "name":"f" }],
 "test-3": [{ "name":"i" }], 
"test-4": [{ "name":"k" }], 
"test-5": [{ "name":"l" }], 
}
```

Also, later on i may like to add additional values to the keys for example in test-1:
"test-1": [{ "name":"a", **"new_name":"new"** }]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your curly brackets, but this creates a map:

```
def original = [
    [branch: "test", name: 'a', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test", name: 'b', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test", name: 'c', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-1", name: 'd', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-1", name: 'e', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-2", name: 'f', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-2", name: 'g', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-2", name: 'h', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-3", name: 'i', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-3", name: 'j', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-4", name: 'k', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-5", name: 'l', image_name: 'abc'],
]

println original
    .groupBy { branch -> branch.branch }
    .collectEntries { key,value -> [(key) : [name : value.get(0).name]] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not positive how to format the result like you want it but finding the first instance of each branch is fairly easy.

```
result = [:]
for (map in LUT)
{
    if (!result.containsKey(map['branch']))
    {
        println map['name'] // prints the unique name
        result.put(map['branch'], map['name'])
    }
}
```

Comment: this will result in = [test:a, test-1:d, test-2:f, test-3:i, test-4:k, test-5:l], but what i want is a list of list or hash with keys (test,test-1,test2,....) and name,,,,  As i am interested in only every first branch in the list, this is what i am trying to explain in the example result above

Comment: You solution is a 1 to 1 mapping,  and what i want is to make 'branch' as a key, so i can add more elements to that branch,

Comment: Yeah I'm not positive how to get the list format like you want but the point of this was just to show how to loop through the original maps and find the first instance of each branch.